# Attempting to end CMD after Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2008, batch-file

I am running a Batch file on which is located on my DC.

explorer.exe =

taskmgr.exe

end;

end;

The batch file works fine and does what I need. The thing is that when I run this batch it forces the Task Manager above all windows until it is either minimized or closed. It requires interaction in order to un-prioritize it. I cant find a proper argument to end the CMD entirely. When I close the CMD manually it un-prioritizes the Task Manager window.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would that be at all useful to have a script that makes explorer.exe = taskmgr.exe?  Have you tried exit instead?

Comment: In Taskmgr there is a menu option under view `Always on top`.  uncheck that option.  Also, the correct command to exit the batch file is `exit`

Comment: @Richie086 These are the 2 tools that I need to launch anywhere in my domain at start-up.

Comment: @uSlackr I tried adding the 'Exit' at the end of the file but no luck. I also unchecked all options under 'Options' Tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should look into using the [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) command in the batch file rather than calling the applications directly. This will allow the applications to launch, but the script execution will continue. I'm not really sure what explorer.exe = taskmgr.exe does for you as from [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35938) it appears to be treated equivalently to a space character, but an example script that starts both apps with high priority and exits follows:

```
start /high taskmgr.exe
start /high explorer.exe
exit
```

Comment: Adding the 'Start /high' resolved the CMD Window issue. As for the '=', this brings up your 'Computer' where you can view all drives available. This helps when keeping track of drives is essential. Thank you for your help, very well appreciated.